# Solving an ODE using the Taylor Method Help?

Tags: differential-equations, education

Not sure how to proceed after this...

```
y'[t_] = -(1 + 2*t)*y[t]*y[t];
y''[t_] = -2*y^2 - 2 (1 + 2*t) (-1 + 2*t)*y[t]^3;
y[0] = 1;
e1[h_] = y[0] + h*y'[1]; (*the approximation of y[1] with order 1*)
e2[h_] = y[0] + h*y'[1] + .5*h^2*y''[1]; (*the approximation of y[1] with order 2*)
For[h = .5, h >= 2^-10, h/2,
 Print[ h, "  ", e1[h], "  ", e2[h]];
```

Lost on how I'm supposed to get `y[1]` on *Mathematica*?
I could solve this if I was using pen and paper, but seems completely alien to me with the code.

After working on it a bit by hand, I added what `y[t]` should be with the given conditions and just added it into the code:

```
y'[t_] = -(1 + 2*t)*y[t]*y[t];
y''[t_] = -2*y[t]^2 - 2 (1 + 2*t) (-1 + 2*t)*y[t]^3;
y[0] = 1;
y[t_] = 1/(t^2 + t + 1);
e1[h_] = y[1] + h*y'[1];
e2[h_] = y[1] + h*y'[1] + .5*h^2*y''[1];
For[h = .5, h >= 2^-10, h = h/2, 
 Print[ h, "  ", (e1[h] - y[1])/h, "  ", (e2[h] - y[1])/h]]
```

Comment: should I just use dsolve to get y[1] and then proceed?

Comment: Code tips: (1) Equations are coded with `==` instead of `=`. (2) Comments are coded thus `(* comment *)`, not with `//`, which means something else entirely. -- Math note: I'm not familiar with the term "Taylor Method", but Taylor series would have `y`, `y'`, `y''` all evaluated at the same value of `t`, either `0` or `1`, not a mix.

Comment: @xzczd The OP might be trying to code a second-order Euler-type numerical method, using the truncated Taylor series as a local approximation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I knew the comments don't work, sorry I edited that in only for the purpose of asking the question on here.

If I am to do it at 0, wouldn't it just give me -y[1] as y' would essentially just be 0?

Isn't order 1 of taylor method also the same as the euler method? Or that's what how I was familiar with at least while order 2 meant to go upto y''

Comment: sorry I will edit it right now.
I do have it working I believe (i'll add my edited code in the question), but I just solved the first degree DE by hand and input y[t] and I'm not sure if I'm supposed to do that

Comment: It seems to me you want something like `y[h] = y[0] + h*y'[0]` in the order-1 case and `y[h] = y[0] + h*y'[0] + .5*h^2*y''[0]` in the order-2 case (for the first step). ***But*** I wouldn't code it in terms of direct assignments to `y[h]`, `y[2h]`, `y[3h]`, etc.

Comment: (1) You're just interested in the error in the first step?  (2) Consider using `Table[]` and `TableForm[]`, instead of `For[]` and `Print[]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think you're right. Possible reference for Taylor method: http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~atkinson/m171.dir/sec_6-10.pdf

Comment: @johnson You're trying to solve 2 different ODE `y'[t_] = -(1 + 2*t)*y[t]*y[t]` and `y''[t_] = -2*y[t]^2 - 2 (1 + 2*t) (-1 + 2*t)*y[t]^3;`?

Comment: I thoguht because it's a ODE, I have to use the chain rule to derive y' which led me to:

`y''[t_] = -2*y[t]^2-2(1+2*t)(-1+2*t)*y[t]^3`

Also, @MichaelE2 I think you're right about the 0 too reading the link that @xzxzd posted, but my error valuations are crazy off I think using:
`(e1(h)-y(1))/h`

Comment: Then your calculation for `y''[t]` is wrong. (you calculated this by hand?) Just try `D[-(1 + 2*t)*y[t]*y[t], t]`. Well, with all due respect, you should put a bit more effort into learning the basic usage of _Mathematica_.

Comment: By the definitions in your (second) code, `(e1[h] - y[1])/h` equals the constant `y'[1]`, which is `1/3`.  That agrees with the output.

Answer (score 3):

I've hesitated for a while, but finally decided to post this as an answer. The following is an implementation for Taylor method. Please read it carefully with the help of document. Currently you may feel it obscure, but I believe you're able to understand it with the help of <kbd>F1</kbd>.

```
(* Analytic solution *)
asol = DSolve[{y[0] == 1,
    y'[t] == -(1 + 2*t)*y[t]*y[t]}, y, t][[1, 1, -1]]
(* Function[{t}, 1/(1 + t + t^2)] *)

(* Implementation for Taylor method *)    
Clear[y, Derivative]
y'[t_] = -(1 + 2*t)*y[t]*y[t];
Derivative[n_][y][t_] = D[y'[t], {t, n - 1}];
rhsgenerator[n_] := 
 Function[{t0, yt0, h}, #] &[
  Normal@Series[y[t], {t, t0, n}] /. t -> t0 + h /. y[t0] -> yt0]

(* 1st order right hand side approximation *)
rhs1 = rhsgenerator[1]

(* 2nd order right hand side approximation *)    
rhs2 = rhsgenerator[2]

solver[rhs_, initvalue_, tbegin_, tend_, step_] := 
 Transpose@{#, FoldList[rhs[#2, #1, step] &, N@initvalue, Most@#]} &@
  Range[tbegin, tend, step]

With[{init = 1, xl = 0, xr = 1, h = 1/5}, 
 ListPlot[solver[#, init, xl, xr, h] & /@ {rhs1, rhs2}, PlotStyle -> PointSize@Medium, 
   PlotRange -> All]~Show~Plot[asol[t], {t, xl, xr}, PlotRange -> All]]

With[{init = 1, xl = 0, xr = 1, h = 1/5}, 
 ListPlot[solver[#, init, xl, xr, h][[All, 2]] - asol@Range[xl, xr, h] & /@ {rhs1, 
    rhs2}, PlotStyle -> PointSize@Medium, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Error of 1st order formula", "Error of 2nd order formula"}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]